# @commands.has_permissions not checking for permissions

Tags: discord.py

So basically what I am doing is trying to write a very basic kick and ban command to use for my discord bot. I've looked through many different tutorials and similar questions asked, but I simply cannot find a fix to this.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await ctx.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{user} has been kicked successfully")
```

When I have the bot up and running, everyone is able to kick everybody else regardless of whether they have permissions to kick members or not, even though I have specified it to check if the user is able to kick people. I want it so that if a user does not have permissions to kick members, they shouldn't be able to kick anyone. I am fairly new to coding, and any help is appreciated. If anyone would like to check for the rest of the code in my program, I am happy to post it, but for now I don't see a reason to have to.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the command that is running?  Do you have another command aliased to "kick"?  If you add some logging to this command, do you see your `print`s in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
await ctx.kick(reason=reason)
```

You're trying to kick the context.  Kick the member instead:

```
await user.kick(reason=reason)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, even after changing my context to user, it still looks like anybody can kick anybody else even without permissions. Any other ideas why this may be? If you need any extra information, I am happy to provide it.