# How to check permissions of a specific user in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord moderation bot and the code for the ban feature is this:

```
    @client.command(name="ban")
async def banpeep(ctx,member: discord.Member, *reason):
    if has_permissions(ban_members=True) or has_permissions(administrator=True): 
        reason=' '.join(reason)
        if reason == '':
            reason = "Deserves to be banned"
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Banned {member} for reason: "+reason,color=0x72d345)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        message=ctx.message
        await message.add_reaction(str(""))
        if not member.bot:
            await member.send(f"You have been banned from the server by {ctx.author} for reason: {reason}")
    elif has_permissions(ban_members=False) and has_permissions(administrator=False):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You don't have permission to ban members!",color=0x72d345)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Sorry stackoverflow kind of ruins my indentation, but you can kind of see what I am going for. The bug is that has_permissions() checks the permissions of the bot, not the user. I want to check if the author has permission to ban members or is an admin. I recently discovered this bug when a regular user banned half the members of my server by just spamming this command. I did from `discord.commands import has_permissions` so that's why I'm not doing commands.has_permissions. How do I check a permissions from a specific user? Would I do something like `ctx.author.check_permissions()` or something. I would like to get the data the same way I do with has_permissions. I've spent over 3 hours looking through stack overflow answers and documentation, but all of them are not for what I'm doing or just are old. I'm don't know if this is the rewrite or not, but I installed this from source so I assume it's the rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the command off with something like this:

```
@client.command(aliases=['purge'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
  Code goes here
```

This will check if the user has the specified permission that is in the parenthesis. Add this if there is a error

```
@ban.error
async def ban_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('Sorry you are not allowed to use this command!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I know if the user doesn't have permission to ban members? Would I just add something like @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=False) at the end and than define another async function? I won't be able to test it out until some friends are online, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry I didn't include this in my first comment, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055224/commands-has-permissions-not-checking-for-permissions) post here, that solution doesn't work, but I can't really test it. Are you sure this checks for the user permissions and not just the permissions of the bot?

Comment: @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)

Comment: but how would i know if they didn't have the correct permissions?

Comment: If they dont have the right perms then the command won't run for them

Comment: but i would want to send a message like "You don't have permission to ban members" or something like that, so how would I do that

Comment: Add this line at the end.



    @ban.error
    async def ban_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send('Sorry you are not allowed to use this command!')

Answer (score 0):

The `has_permissions()` decorator should be up at the top of your async statement like so.

```
@client.command(name = "ban")
@has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def banpeep(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
```

Also note, that if a user has the `administrator` permission, they will have the `ban_member` permission.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055224/commands-has-permissions-not-checking-for-permissions) post here, that method actually doesn't work, and I haven't been able to test it, but can you confirm that this actually checks for the permissions of the issuer of the command and not just the bot permissions, I've been having a lot of trouble with this checking lately, so if you could just confirm, it would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if this feature has been errored in the past, but I can confirm from the **latest versions of discord.py** that this does work correctly.